# What is a boolean flag 

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm taking a course in Visual Basic 2010 and I'm trying to get a grasp on this new term called a flag. I kind of understand that it has something to do with a boolean condition. I don't quite understand what a flag is. I see references to it using the term flag. I understand it has something to do when a boolean, a condition triggers a flag. But what is the flag. How do you identify it? Can somebody give me an example.

Comment: Are you talking about Enum Flags Attribute ?

Comment: See: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, "Flag" is just another term for a true/false condition.

It may have more specific meanings in more specific contexts. For instance, a CPU may keep "arithmetic flags", each one indicating a true/false condition resulting from the previous arithmetic operation. For instance, if the previous operation was an "ADD", then the flags would indicate whether the result of the add was zero, less than zero, or greater than zero.

I believe the term comes from flags used to signal a go/no go condition, like, a railroad flagman indicating whether or not it is safe for the train to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You hear this quite a bit with BOOL being a 'Flag' since there are only 2 outcomes either TRUE or FALSE. Using BOOL in your decision making processes is an easy way to 'flag' a certain outcome if the condition is met.

An example could be:

```
if ($x == TRUE) {
 // DO THIS
{
else {
 //Flag not tripped, DO THIS
}
```

Comment: Correct PHP, I dont mess with .NET just trying to give a very basic example all could understand

Comment: Here is probably a more appealing thread from an MSDN site using VB.net and BOOLEAN... Hope this helps

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/vblanguage/thread/73ba02b8-573a-4fce-a2b4-a5c3063c6cfd

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations). It can be used to pack 32 booleans into one integer. Here's a sample:

```
Dim flags As Integer
Const ADMINISTRATOR = 1
Const USER = 2
Const BLUE = 4
Const RED = 8

flags = ADMINISTRATOR or BLUE

If flags and ADMINISTRATOR then
    ' Do something since the person is an admin
End If
```

The `or`s add flags and `and`s check if the flag is set.

Now we can check up to 32 booleans for this one variable. Great for storing in a database. You can use bigger datatypes, like a `long` to store more.